# Standard Deviation in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to write a function in clojure to find the standard deviation of a sequence (vector). So far I have defined a function to find the average of a set of numbers, but I am having an issue with a couple of things.

First I am confused over how to use a square root and powers in clojure. Second I am trying to figure out how to pull out each element individually out the vector and subtract the mean from it and then square it.

So far this is my function

```
(defn mean [a] (/ (reduce + a) (count a))) 

(defn standarddev [a] (Math/sqrt (/ (reduce + (map square #(- % (mean a) a))) (- (count a) 1 ))))
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a double, you can use Java's Math class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) to perform calculations like sqrt.  You don't need to do anything special to access the Math class, because Clojure make all java.lang classes available to you w/o import.

Comment: I keep trying to use Math.sqrt, but I get errors everytime I try even to do something simple like (Math.sqrt 4)

Comment: @user3483844 you should be using `Math/sqrt`, not `Math.sqrt`

Comment: @Josh Okay, that worked, thanks. Now I just gotta figure out how to iterate through the list so I can get the summation of (x-meanx)^2 part

Comment: @user3483844 see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close.
Assuming you already have the following functions

```
(defn square [n] (* n n))

(defn mean [a] (/ (reduce + a) (count a)))
```

2 problems with your standarddev function

```
(defn standarddev [a] (Math/sqrt (/ (map square (map - a (mean a))) (- (count a) 1 ))))
```

1) `(map - a (mean a))` 
Doesn't work because you are subtracting a "number" from a "vector".
To fix repeat `(mean a)` as many times as there are elements in "a" 
Easiest and by no means efficient solution would be

```
(map - a (repeat (mean a)))
```

2) (map square (map - a (mean a))) Doesn't work because of #1 above and because map returns a "vector".
To fix sum the elements of the vector

```
(reduce + (map square (map - a (repeat (mean a)))))
```

Your standard dev function should now be

```
  (defn standarddev [a] 
      (Math/sqrt (/ 
                    (reduce + (map square (map - a (repeat (mean a))))) 
                    (- (count a) 1 ))))
```

Comment: What does the (repeat (mean a)) part do? I tested it and it works, but what is the definition behind repeat?

Comment: it simply repeats the value that "(mean a)" returns as many times as you want. Not an elegant solution but the simplest to get your function to work.

Comment: I tested repeat just on it's own (repeat [1 2 3 4]) and it returned the vector [1 2 3 4] repeatedly infinitely. How does repeat(mean a) allow mean to map my mean function to each value in a given vector and not infinitely? I'm just confused as how it works.

Comment: map takes only what it needs. so if i have (map + [ 1 2 3] [ 4 5]) i will get (5 7) the 3 drops off.

Answer (score 1):

You can gently increase performance by getting rid of the `map` altogether

```
(def square #(* % %))

(defn standard-deviation
  [a]
  (let [mn (mean a)]
    (Math/sqrt
      (/ (reduce #(+ %1 (square (- %2 mn))) 0 a)
         (dec (count a))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

> First I am confused over how to use a square root and powers in clojure.

To square something, just multiply it by itself:

```
(defn square [n]
  (* n n))
```

If you want a power higher than 2, you could also use an exponentiation function:

```
(defn exp [x n]
  (reduce * (repeat n x)))
```

> Second I am trying to figure out how to pull out each element individually out the vector and subtract the mean from it and then square it.

The Clojure (functional) way of iterating through a seq is to use `map`.  Map takes a function and a collection and returns the result of applying that function to each element of the collection.

```
(defn squares [avg coll] (map #(square (- % avg)) coll))
```

Final standard-deviation function, using the above 2 functions and your mean:

```
(defn standard-deviation [coll]
  (let [avg (mean coll)
        squares (squares avg coll)
        total (count coll)]
    (Math/sqrt (/ (reduce + squares) (- total 1)))))
```

inspiration from: https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/01_primitive-data/1-20_simple-statistics.asciidoc

Comment: I think I might have it, but I am getting an erorr when I try to apply my formula to a vector like say (standarddev [1 2 3 4])          What I have so far is                                                                                                                     (defn standarddev [a] (Math/sqrt (/ (map square (map - a (mean a))) (- (count a) 1 ))))

Comment: @user3483844 check your inputs to `map`, you only want to pass them a function and a collection, you're passing 2 collections (which is valid, but not what you want to do here).

Comment: So, Here's what I wanna do. I have my list of numbers. First I wanna subtract the mean from each one of the elements of the vector. Which I can do with map I believe. Next I wanna square each element which I can do with map, and finally I wanna add all the squares up which I can do with map. Correct?

Comment: `(map #(square (- % avg)) coll)` subtracts the mean from each element and then squares it.  Note that `%` represents the current element.  To sum all of those, use reduce like so: `(reduce + squares)`.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how I can make it work in my own formula and don't wanna just copy-paste because that would be cheating.  I'm confused what the # means. So you are mapping the function square to a collection called coll, but how does (- % avg) work? I'm lost.

Comment: `#(- % avg)` explanation:  `#()` creates an anonymous function.  `map` then calls that function n number of times, each time with the next element of the collection.  When you use the `#()` syntax, you can use `%` or `%1` to denote the first parameter that was passed, `%2` for the second, and so on.

If you don't like that syntax, you can also just do it like this: `(fn [x] (- x avg))`.  There is no difference at all.

Comment: okay, my new formula is (defn standarddev [a] (Math/sqrt (/ (reduce + (map square #(- % (mean a) a))) (- (count a) 1 )))), but I am still getting an error when trying to run it with a simple function like (standarddev [1 2 3 4])

Answer (score 0):

Corrected sample standard deviation, same as in R `sd` function

```
(defn sd [abc] 
    (Math/sqrt
        (/ (reduce + (map #(* % %)
            (map #(- % (/ (reduce + abc) (count abc))) abc)))
           (dec (count abc))
        )
    )
)
```